# Hide path (id) in solr result

Tags: php, linux, pdf, solr, path

I am using Solr 7.5.0. And using Linux Mint Tara.
I have a program that can call only "id" of json result in solr.
this is the HTML code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title></title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="solr2.php" method="post">
         value:<input type="text" name="value">
         <input type="submit" name="submit">
     </form>
</body>
</html>
```

this is the solr2.php code :

```
<?php

$value = $_POST['value'];
$cari = file_get_contents("http://localhost:8983/solr/pdfindex/select?q=" .$value. "&rows=100&start=0&hl=true");
$contents = utf8_encode($cari);
$results = json_decode($cari);
$numFound = json_encode($results->response->numFound);

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numFound-1; $i++) {
$tab[$i] = $results->response->docs[$i]->id;

}

for ($i = 0; $i <= $numFound-1; $i++) {
echo '<tr>
    <td style=text-align: center;><a
href="'.$tab[$i].'">'.$tab[$i].'</a></td>
    </tr>';
}
?>
```

and the result would be :

> /home/kevin/Documents/referensi/umkm_digital/Strategi Pemberdayaan UMKM Menghadapi Pasar Bebas Asean .pdf
>   /home/kevin/Documents/referensi/umkm_digital/2012_Strategi Pemberdayaan UMKM Menghadapi Pasar Bebas Asean.pdf

the question is: Can I hide the path and show only the pdf title?

Pardon my bad english :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`basename` in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php).

> Given a string containing the path to a file or directory, this function will return the trailing name component.

```
> php -r "var_dump(basename('/home/kevin/Documents/referensi/umkm_digital/Strategi Pemberdayaan UMKM Menghadapi Pasar Bebas Asean .pdf /home/kevin/Documents/referensi/umkm_digital/2012_Strategi Pemberdayaan UMKM Menghadapi Pasar Bebas Asean.pdf'));"
string(64) "2012_Strategi Pemberdayaan UMKM Menghadapi Pasar Bebas Asean.pdf"
```

Also be aware that you should escape any user input you send to Solr, as you'll otherwise expose your Solr server to malicious requests from users. If the user is authenticated and trusted, this might not be an issue, but if the input you're using is available to general users that you should not trust, make sure to escape it.

The easiest way to do this is to use a library for accessing Solr, [such as Solarium](https://github.com/solariumphp/solarium).